# Codable Swift Structs for JSON with Nested Empty Array

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have the following Swift code with some sample JSON that I'm trying to decode. You can drop this into a Playground to try it for yourself:

```
let json = """
{
  "sessionState": "abc",
  "methodResponses": [
    [
      "Mailbox/get",
      {
        "state": "92",
        "accountId": "xyz"
      },
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}
"""

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!

if let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JMAPResponse.self, from: data) {
  print(object)
}else{
  print("JMAP decode failed")
}
```

I had no idea how to handle the nested array, so [I used quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), but what it generated still doesn't work.

Here is my root element with the nested array:

```
//Root
struct JMAPResponse: Codable{
  var sessionState: String?
  var methodResponses: [[JMAPResponseChild]]
}
```

Here is the `enum` that QuickType suggested I use to process the `methodResponse` node:

```
//Nested array wrapper
enum JMAPResponseChild: Codable{
  case methodResponseClass(JMAPMethodResponse)
  case string(String)

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
      if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
        self = .string(x)
        return
      }
      if let x = try? container.decode(JMAPMethodResponse.self) {
        self = .methodResponseClass(x)
        return
      }
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JMAPResponseChild.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JMAPResponseChild"))
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .methodResponseClass(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .string(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the next level down:

```
//No-key data structure (Mailbox/get, {}, 0)
struct JMAPMethodResponse: Codable{
  var method: String
  var data: [JMAPMailboxList]
  var id: String 

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(method)
    try container.encode(data)
    try container.encode(id)
  }
}
```

And finally, the lowest-level node:

```
struct JMAPMailboxList: Codable{
  var state: String?
  var accountId: String?
}
```

It still can't decode the structure successfully. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Never print a hard coded string in the `catch` clause, print the actual error instead. `catch { print(error) }`.

Comment: Great point, thank you. I typically do in other areas, but overlooked it with encoding JSON because sometimes the errors are cryptic and not helpful. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JMAPResponseChild` is decoding an array expecting either a `String` or `JMAPMethodResponse`. The array looks like this:

```json
    [
      "Mailbox/get",
      {
        "state": "92",
        "accountId": "xyz"
      },
      "0"
    ]
```

It actually contains either a `String` or `JMAPMailboxList` (not `JMAPMethodResponse`). If you change all the `JMAPMethodResponse` references in `JMAPResponseChild` to `JMAPMailboxList` it should work. You will have to do some post processing or change your code to translate that array of three values into `JMAPMethodResponse`.

You might structure your `JMapMethodResponse` more like this:

```swift
struct JMAPMethodResponse: Codable {
  var method: String
  var data: JMAPMailboxList
  var id: String

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let values = try container.decode([JMAPResponseChild].self)

    guard case .string(let extractedMethod) = values[0] else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(String.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "First array element not String"))
    }
    method = extractedMethod
    guard case .methodResponseClass(let extractedData) = values[1] else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JMAPMailboxList.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Second array element not JMAPMailboxList"))
    }
    data = extractedData
    guard case .string(let extractedId) = values[2] else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(String.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Third array element not String"))
    }
    id = extractedId
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(JMAPResponseChild.string(method))
    try container.encode(JMAPResponseChild.methodResponseClass(data))
    try container.encode(JMAPResponseChild.string(id))
  }
}
```

Then you can just get an array of those in your response:

```swift
struct JMAPResponse: Codable{
  var sessionState: String?
  var methodResponses: [JMAPMethodResponse]
}
```

I don't know if the encoder or decoder guarantee ordering in the array. If they don't this could randomly break.

Comment: It will be decoded in the order it appears in the json, that is my understanding.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I'm still studying your code to wrap my head around it, but it's making sense and is working well.